# Outlook addin not loading in outlook 2013(64 bit) with windows 10(64 bit)

Tags: registry, vsto, windows-10, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I am developing an outlook vsto add in.When I install it on win 10 with office 2013, both 64 bit, and start outlook.The addin is in inactive state .I enable it from the trust centre settings and restart outlook.But it again automatically goes into inactive state.I checked the registry entry and there the load behaviour is automatically changed to 2.I changed it to 3,and started the outlook.Then again the addin is in inactive state and the registry entry is also automatically changed to 2.Please suggest what should I do?

Comment: Try to set the VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS and VSTO_LOGALERTS environment variables, maybe that helps you to diagnose the issue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269003(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure that all the required prerequsites were included to the installer and installed on the end-user machine before the add-in is loaded.

Do you get any exceptions in the code? Or use any platform specific components?

Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again. Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) article.

Comment: I read the article and my application goes into soft disable, everytime I start the outlook.And the plugin works fine on another machine having the same configuration.Also the plugin start up code is handled.So, please let me know if there could be some other cause of the issue.

Comment: Most probably an exception is fired in the code. I'd recommend debugging the code carefully.